# Object Expected JS Error For Application running on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6, java-6, rhel5, object-expected

We have two different servers running our web application, one is Windows and other is Linux Red Hat. Both the server has same Tomcat(6) and JDK (v6u20). The application running on Windows work fine, but the one running on Linux keeps throwing JS errors:

"Message: Object expected"

Can anyone point me to the possible cause of this error on linux and not on windows?

Thanks,

Noman a.

Comment: We have tried deploying the application on ubuntu and the JS errors are not encountered on ubuntu. Its just the RHEL that is having the issues. Any help, guys??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be issue with the apache. We were using mixed version modules.

Upgrading to the latest Apache with latest modules resolved the issue.